# Do I need to purchase pure sine wave UPS for Mac mini M1?

Tags: ups

I heard from the APC UPS sales that I need to purchase more expensive pure sine wave UPS for Mac mini M1. Is this correct?

Comment: APC (any manufacturer) is going to tell you to buy pure sine-wave.  They're better.  And more expensive.  Whether the "better" is something you need... well, probably not for home use.

Comment: The Mini runs fine on whatever comes out of the wall, so it should be fine with whatever any UPS can supply.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be another example of "Be wary of anyone who sells $X and tells you that you need $X." Ideally, the person who figures out what you need isn't the person who sells it to you.

Answer (score 1):

If this is true, I have never heard it before, nor have I ever bought any "special" UPSes for my Macs.

Therefore, I am tempted to say that it is *not* true, but I am not an expert, I only have personal knowledge and experience which leads me to believe it is not true.

I hope this is helpful and I am hopeful that someone with more expertise will chime in.

Comment: Given a choice, yes, buy pure sine-wave UPS's.  Advantage... much cleaner power vs an approximated waveform.  Disadvantage... usually MUCH more expensive.  It's not likely that your Mac is going to be able to tell the difference, unless you buy some horribly-cheap approximated UPS.